# How can I change a file's timestamp from the file name in Linux?

Tags: linux, touch

I have a set of images I got from a tour I was on. The file names have the timestamp embedded (e.g., "2015-07-04-15-02-14.jpg"). Sadly, they are all time/date stamped with the date they were downloaded, not when the pix were taken. To integrate them into the pictures I took during the tour, I'd like to change the timestamp given the file names. (That's the reverse of what people usually need.)

The files will all be in their own directory, so I need to read the entire directory and touch the files according to the characters in the file name.

I'm no Linux scripting expert, but if someone could help me figure out the code to do that, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a fairly simple shell script, which uses your naming convention to obtain timestamp values for the [`touch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/touch.html) command, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in $*
do
    test -f "$file" || continue
    ts=$(basename "$file" .jpg | sed -e 's/-//g')
    touch -t $ts $file
done
```

The script uses [`basename`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/basename.html) to strip the ".jpg" suffix and then uses [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html) to remove all of the dashes.  Your remaining digits happen to be in the same order as the timestamp values used by `touch`, so it should work.

You would use the script like this

```
./myscript *.jpg
```

If you want to see it doing anything (except possible error messages), you would add a line with `ls` (for some reason, GNU `touch` lacks the verbose `-v` option provided by comparable utilities with as `ln` and `cp`):

```
ls -l $file
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the man page of [touch](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?touch)
Please see the useful options

> -a     change only the access time
>
> -m     change only the
>
> modification time   -t STAMP
>           use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time